# How to Increase Mic sensitivity

Tags: audio, recording

I am new to android.I am trying to capture  very low volume sound .I want to know how can I increase sensitivity of the mic of my phone. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can apply a scale factor to all your samples, but note that this will amplify background noise too.

Comment: You can't increase microphone sensitivity programmatically, but you can adjust mixer parameters, and process your recorded samples with a compressor and limiter.

Comment: Hi  paul  Thanks how can i amplify sound  could you please give example  Hi Brad Thanks could you please give me some example how to adjust mixer parameter and how to use compressor and limiter

Comment: Hi paul Thanks how can i amplify sound could you please give example

Comment: Hi Brad Thanks could you please give me some example how to adjust mixer parameter and how to use compressor and limiter